# How to Append SQL Output into a New Table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I am working on creating a trend line for a daily count I am getting from a SQL query. Each time the query runs, I get a count and the current date.

I need a way to record the output of the query into a new table and continue to append each time the query runs. The appended table would looke like this:

| Count | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 250 | 10/12/2022 |
| 257 | 10/13/2022 |
| 220 | 10/14/2022 |

This table would allow me to create a trend line. I am also open to a different approach if there is a better way.

Comment: Power BI is not a database. You must store these values somewhere (e.g. in a database) and build the Power BI report to use this as a data source.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use power query append option.
[image: Power query]
Should solve your issue.